# The name ' ' does not exist in the current context after trying to access a public variable from code behind in aspx meta tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, meta-tags, twitter-card

Note that This error does not appear locally on my machine but only after i published my webforms.
1-I am trying to create twitter cards in my webform so i am using meta tags for that.
2- I declared some variables as public string in code behind of the aspx page.
3- I added the meta tags to the aspx page and when i tried accessing these variables using ex: <%=title%>
4- this error appeared : The name 'title' does not exist in the current context. 
Can someone please tell me what is going wrong>
Code Behind:

```
        public string title="",desc="",img="",url="";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();
            conx = new SqlConnection(constr);
            string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                FillData(id);
                Page.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void FillData(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                conx.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "selectListArticle";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(id));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = conx;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    title = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    lblTitle.Text = title;
                    lblDate.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                    desc = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                    lblIntro.Text = desc;
                    img = "~" + dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
                    Image1.ImageUrl = img;
                    Image1.AlternateText = dt.Rows[0][8].ToString();
                    string tags = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                    bindTags(tags);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conx.Close();
            }
        }
```

And this is the Aspx Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Article.aspx.cs" Inherits="CosmOnList.Article" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@Name"/>
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Name"/>
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="<%= title %>"/>
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="<%= desc %>"/>
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="<%= img %>"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Aside from your problem: do **NOT** cache connection objects, make sure to dispose them and command and adapter with `using` blocks

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for your note, will do. I just checked it out.

Comment: Change public title="" to public string title {get; set;}

Comment: @Sergey Still showing the same error.

Comment: did you try to change it to twTitle for example? or put after desc in a view?

Comment: @Sergey Changing it did not work, What do you mean should i do with views?

Comment: I think that the common data binding is not working. Try to type just text instead of <%. I am sure it will be working.

Comment: @Sergey Well yes it works but i don't want the data to be static.

Comment: You see runat="server" on the content tag? It means that only content tag can be manipulated on the server. Metatags are not since they don't have runat. And by the way they are supposed to be in the header section.  You have to find  if there is a way to change metatags content. Maybe Javascript will work, Try to google.

Answer (score 0):

Sample using the `Page_Load` event.

Use *databinding* code in the embedded code (`<%#`).

aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="<%# title %>" />
</asp:Content>
```

Code-behind:

```
public string title = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    title = "the title";
    Page.Header.DataBind();    // <-- the key is this line.
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this kept showing the same error.